# How can I show a different notification each time which open different activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-broadcast

I am trying to build an affirmation app which shows notification as an affirmation text and when user clicks on the notification it should take it to an activity, So far i am able to display notifications on hourly basis but i have no idea how to display different notifications each hour which opens a different activity each time because there is gonna be a random list of affirmations which will be displayed as notifications.

EDIT:
My MainActivity:

```
  private void hourly()
       {
        Calendar calender=Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),notification_receiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingintent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//        calender.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
////        calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
////        calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        alarmmanager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval=60000;
        alarmmanager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                interval,
                interval, pendingintent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

My notification_receiver class:

```
       public class notification_receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ArrayList<String> notificationTexts = null;
    notificationTexts.add("This is a nice day"); // this will go to notificationTexts in position 0;
    notificationTexts.add("This is nice morning");
    Random rand = new Random();
    int n = rand.nextInt(notificationTexts.size());
    NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent repeating_activity=new Intent(context,repeating_activity.class);
    repeating_activity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeating_activity,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentTitle("Affirmation")
            .setContentText(notificationTexts.get(n))
            .setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());

}
```

}

Comment: What is an affirmation app? Can you also show what you have done?

Comment: Umm its like user will be asked hourly or daily affirmations if it selects hourly then a notification will be shown on his phone every hour and it will show some positive text as a title and when the user click on the text it will take it to some activity in my case that activity is gonna be an image with that positive thought written on it which was shown in a notification title.

Comment: You can also check this app called My affirmations it is alot similar to what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a mechanism to show the notifications so what you are needing is a sort of backend where you can select a random text linked to a certain activity of your app.

In your main activity you can have 2 lists:

```
private ArrayList<Srtring> notificationTexts;
private ArrayList<Class> activitiesToStart;
```

Whith these two you add the text for your affirmations and the activity class you want to start under the same index of position in the list.

For example:

```
notificationTexts.add("This is a nice day"); // this will go to notificationTexts in position 0;
activitiesToStart.add(TheNiceDayActivity.class); //this will go to the activitiesToStart also in position 0;
```

In the mechanism you already have working, when you prepare the notification, you just have to calculate a random number between 0 and the length of either Lists, and pick the text from the first list and the activity from the second one. To pick the corresponding element you do it with `list.get(position);`

Once you got the activity, you create the PendingIntent that goes in the notification setup at the time of building it.

I haven't tried it but it should give you an idea on how it can be done.

EDIT I

A random number between 0 and 19 (including the 19) can be calculated with:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int n = rand.nextInt(20);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining all this but i dont understand some things here :1)How do i generate a random number ?2)How do i update my notification title and pending intent according to the randomly selected text and activity?

Comment: How are you building the notification that you have working? Edit and add it to your question.

Comment: Ok i'm gonna try to implement what you explained me here then i will post the full code here, Please be subscribed to the post and thanks sir.

Comment: Hi please check my code i edited my post as you asked.I tried what you told me to do but i failed to apply your method,In this code i am generating a notification after every 60 seconds when the button is pressed.

Comment: Hey i got it , i did it:) Thanks:)

Comment: 1- In case you need different activities to be started for different texts you can use a paralel list activitiesToStart with the same n where you previously store the class of the activity to use when creating the pending intent. 2- If this helped you please check my answer as accepted :)

Comment: Hi..Yeah thanks sir actually i wanted to do it but i just dont know how to i tried to use the variable i and n like this(if i==n)then change the value of n? but it is not working can you please explain me how can i show certain acitivity for certain notification(in my case certain notification content) without randoming them.

Comment: Please help me :(